# Mobiscroll onBeforeShow, set Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobiscroll

How do I call the onBeforeShow event with mobiscroll?

```
$('#starttime').mobiscroll('setValue', value).time({
        theme: 'jqm',
        display: 'modal',
        mode: 'clickpick',
        stepMinute: 10,
        onBeforeShow:  
 });
```

I need to set the time right before it shows. If I try to do it on document ready the input field isn't ready yet with the value...

**Edit**

I tried:

```
$('#starttime').mobiscroll('setValue', value).time({
        theme: 'jqm',
        display: 'modal',
        mode: 'clickpick',
        stepMinute: 10,
        onBeforeShow: function(html, inst) {
            start = $('#starttime').val();
            var a = moment();
            var value = a.format('h:mm A');

            }
        });
```

but then I'm getting the error: 'value is not defined'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a callback function.

```
$('#starttime').mobiscroll('setValue', value).time({
        theme: 'jqm',
        display: 'modal',
        mode: 'clickpick',
        stepMinute: 10,
        onBeforeShow: function (html, inst) {
            //Gets called before the scroller appears. The function receives the jQuery object containing the generated html and the scroller instance as parameters
        }
 });
```

http://docs.mobiscroll.com/23/mobiscroll-core

Comment: Thanks I was looking there but this didn't have a code sample...hm but how do I set the value of 'value' if I'm setting it in "onBeforeShow"??

Comment: I have never used mobiscroll but you can try this :
$('#starttime').mobiscroll('setValue', value) inside the callback function

Comment: You also can use the instance "inst" to set the value. http://docs.mobiscroll.com/23/mobiscroll-instance